# Why my systems doesnt free the buffers/cache

Tags: c++, ubuntu, memory, memory-management

I have a memory hungry application. I let it run over night on a system with 32GB RAM. Also ran `free -m -s 20` along with it to see how the memory status changes. My application was the only thing I manually started after restarting my `Ubuntu` (except the terminal of course). let's look at parts of output:

**when the application started:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32100       1428      30671         35         69        594
-/+ buffers/cache:        765      31335
Swap:        32693          0      32693
```

**before the application ends:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32100      31860        240         84          2      17420
-/+ buffers/cache:      14437      17663
Swap:        32693         12      32681
```

**right after the application ends:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32100      18723      13376         84          2      17434
-/+ buffers/cache:       1285      30814
Swap:        32693         12      32681
```

and the status remain same for many hours until I came back in the morning.

**My question is:**
 *Why most of my memory is still considered a `free` part of  `buffers/cache` ? when is this part of memory going to be the `free` part of the overall `Mem:` again?*

I **then** opened a browser, an IDE and some other GUI application to see how and from where the memory is allocated to the new applications:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32100      20378      11721         88        160      18075
-/+ buffers/cache:       2143      29956
Swap:        32693         12      32681
```

Apparently, Free memory from both `Mem:` as well as `buffers/cache:` was allocated to new applications. Can you please interpret this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cached data is also part of the used memory. After a program ends, the data loaded from disk by your program will become a part of the cache. So your system will not free any of the data, but it drops the cached data, if your memory will be needed again. [A more or less funny page, that describes the problem.](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: I feel I'm urged to post this link to Twitter

Comment: @TheSlayer I followed the link you mentioned in your answer, do you agree with the last part? (`How do I see how much free ram I really have?`) is the `free` column of `buffers/cache` my total free memory?